# Can I save Event Grid messages to a file in a storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I am new to Azure and am sending events to Event Grid. I'd like to be able to save these messages as a file (csv or json) and store them in my storage account (blob). Is this possible to do within Azure? If this requires a function or logic app the preferred language would be Python.

Comment: You can use a destination resource such as an Event Hubs with a capture option to the blob storage, see more details in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-event-hubs Note, that this solution doesn't require a  coding, but it is a cost non-effective (price of the capture option is $73/month), otherwise you need to write an EventGridTrigger function for that requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this is possible through Logic Apps. Below is a sample how you can build your flow in your logic apps.

[image]

Below is the Code-view that you can refer to

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@json(triggerBody()?['data'])",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Create_blob_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "headers": {
                        "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderPath": "/container73235051",
                        "name": "@triggerBody()?['id']",
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "contentTransfer": {
                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_resource_event_occurs": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "properties": {
                            "destination": {
                                "endpointType": "webhook",
                                "properties": {
                                    "endpointUrl": "@{listCallbackUrl()}"
                                }
                            },
                            "topic": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/EventGridTopic73253690"
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureeventgrid']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent('b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f')}/providers/@{encodeURIComponent('Microsoft.EventGrid.Topics')}/resource/eventSubscriptions",
                    "queries": {
                        "x-ms-api-version": "2017-09-15-preview"
                    }
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnectionWebhook"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob-2",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob-2",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "azureeventgrid": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureeventgrid",
                    "connectionName": "azureeventgrid",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/azureeventgrid"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, this looks to be exactly what I am looking for. What operation is used as the first step in this workflow? It looks like from the code it is "when a resource event occurs", however I don't seem to have that option as one of my triggers.

Comment: Edit: nevermind I found it.